# Gradle build failed: Execution failed for task ':audioplayers:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I was trying to build a simple xylophone app and needed to add an audio player for it. So I downloaded the best rated dart package to play local audio files: `audioplayers`. After adding it to pubsec.yaml and installing it when I stopped and rebuild my app it crashed and I think it has something to do with Kotlin and `audioplayers` version being incompatibe.

Here's the main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Xylophone());
}

class Xylophone extends StatefulWidget {
  const Xylophone({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _XylophoneState createState() => _XylophoneState();
}

class _XylophoneState extends State<Xylophone> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final player = AudioPlayer();
                player.play('note1');
              },
              child: Text('tap me'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Pubsec.yaml:

```
name: xylophone
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  audioplayers: ^0.19.1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

assets:
  - assets/
```

And this is the error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM T580 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: C:/Users/Ninad/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/Ninad/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/77bab1911042ab2c6d5cc0b2e2ee053c/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/Ninad/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bd92f9b27f3f577322c07e31476e006e/jetified-core-ktx-1.6.0-api.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (18, 32): Unresolved reference: mutableMapOf
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (25, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Ninad/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (26, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Ninad/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (27, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Ninad/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (28, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Ninad/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (34, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Ninad/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (36, 20): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Ninad/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.19.1\android\src\main\kotlin\xyz\luan\audioplayers\AudioplayersPlugin.kt: (37, 22): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Ninad/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':audioplayers:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Please provide detailed answers and helpful solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a bit of research, I came across an answer on Github. So to fix this issue you need to change `ext.kotlin_version` in `build.gradle`. To change that you need to right click on android folder from your project tree > click on Flutter > click on Open Android module in Android Studio > now you can open it in the same window or in a new one > click on Gradle Scripts from project tree> open `build.gradle` (the first file) > finally change the `ext.kotlin_version` parameter to the latest version in my case `1.5.30` and sync gradle project and you will be good to go.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]